# Check Community User's Salesforce Password

Tags: apex, community, soap, customer-community, passwords

I would like to require users to re-enter their password in order to access ePHI (to prevent an unauthorized user from getting access if the authorized user walks away from their desk...)

I have not found a native Apex approach, so followed this recipe using SOAP (tested changing from partner/u to enterprise/c and updating the version to 38.0, 39.0, and 40.0):
http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/verifying-password

This works fine for standard users, but not from my Communities. I have confirmed that API Enabled is true for the user's profile, I have whitelisted all the ip ranges recommended by SF, and have attempted adding the following code to the recipe:

```
    ...
    request.setHeader('SOAPAction', '""');
    request.setHeader('LoginScopeHeader',buildSoapOrganization());
    ...

    public static String buildSoapOrganization() {
        Id organizationId = [SELECT Id FROM Organization LIMIT 1].Id;
        XmlStreamWriter w = new XmlStreamWriter();
        w.writeStartElement('', 'organizationId', 'urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com');
        w.writeCharacters(String.valueOf(organizationId).substring(0,15)); //same result with full orgId or first 15
        w.writeEndElement();
        String xmlOutput = w.getXmlString();
        w.close();
        return xmlOutput;
    }
```

The response comes back with fault:

> INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.

However, when I look at the Login History for the user, there is no new entry reflecting the failed attempts.

Note that most of my testing is done in a sandbox with LOGIN_DOMAIN set to 'test'.

Is there an alternative for confirming the user's SF password, anything else that I would need to add to get this SOAP approach to work, or any other tools for debugging what's wrong with the current SOAP call?

Comment: Please refrain from using ALL CAPS where it is not an acronym or similarly appropriate.

Comment: You can look at the edit history and see what I mean. You used all caps in a few instances where it wasn't really called for. When formatting your posts, you can use **`**bold**`** or *`*italicize*`* your text. In your title, you should not really need to add emphasis.

Comment: Anyone have any answer for it?